# Newtonsoft.Json: Self referencing loop detected for property for azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

I get this error :
Newtonsoft.Json: **Self referencing loop detected for property** when I run my azure function but i have already added a startupFile with the this code

```
  public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            };
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by decorating the property with the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).